# Cambiar JComboBox de color

Tags: java, combobox, color

He estado intentando cambiar el color de un componente ComboBox a naranja (puntualmente, el color 255,153,51), le he cambiado el Background desde el diseñador gráfico de Netbeans y también lo he importado como un componente personalizado con ese color ya puesto, pero a la hora de ejecutar el Frame, el componente vuelve a aparecer con el color gris predeterminado. ¿Alguien podría ayudarme a corregirlo?

```
String[] niveles={"Seleccionar","Primaria","Secundaria","Preparatoria"};
    public RoyalCollege() {
        initComponents();
        setResizable(false);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        DefaultComboBoxModel md=new DefaultComboBoxModel(niveles);
        Nivel.setModel(md);
        ESemestre.setVisible(false);
        Campus.setSelectedItem("Seleccionar");
        EExtraescolar.setVisible(false);
        ETaller.setVisible(false);
        Talleres.setVisible(false);
        EPromedio.setVisible(false);
        TPromedio.setVisible(false);
        BPromedio.setVisible(false);
        Color c=new Color(255,153,51);
        Nivel.setBackground(Color.ORANGE);
        Nivel.setOpaque(true);
        PanelRegistro.revalidate();
        jTabbedPane1.setBackground(new Color(0,0,0));
    }
```

El ComboBox en cuestión es la variable llamada "Nivel"

Comment: Así debe funcionar; ¿Cómo quedó la declaración de `Nivel`?

Answer (score 1):

Si solo desea cambiar solo los colores de la pequeña ventana emergente que aparece para seleccionar los elementos cuando abre el cuadro combinado, esto debería ser suficiente:

```
box.setForeground(new Color(0, 255, 0));
box.setBackground(new Color(255, 153, 51));
```

Con esto modifica solo los colores de los elementos a seleccionar, como se muestra aquí:
[image: Simple]

Si desea modificar todo, incluso los colores del elemento seleccionado o la cara "stand by" del cuadro combinado, tendrá que escribir **su propio Renderizador y Editor**, aquí hay una clase completa como ejemplo para que pueda probar diferentes opciones:

[image: complejo]

```
//no olvides el paquete

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Font;

import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.ListCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicComboBoxEditor;

public class Window extends JFrame {
    
    public Window() {
        createComboBox();
        createWindow();
    }

    private void createComboBox() {
        final String[] niveles={"Seleccionar","Primaria","Secundaria","Preparatoria"};
        final JComboBox box = new JComboBox<>(niveles);
        
        //estas son las opciones simples, si las usas no necesitas el renderizador o editor
        //box.setForeground(new Color(0, 255, 0));
        //box.setBackground(new Color(255, 153, 51));
        
        //si las dos opciones anteriores no son suficientes para usted, 
        //aquí está el código para un editor y un renderizador simples
        box.setRenderer(new MiBoxRenderer());
        box.setEditor(new MiBoxEditor());
        //Es obligatorio que el Editable sea verdadero, de lo contrario, 
        //las modificaciones del renderizador y del editor no funcionarán.
        box.setEditable(true);        
        
        box.setBounds(20, 20, 300, 30);
        box.setVisible(true);
        add(box);
        
    }
    
    private void createWindow() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(new Dimension(600, 400));
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setLayout(null);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Window w = new Window();
        w.setVisible(true);
    }

} 

class MiBoxRenderer extends JLabel implements ListCellRenderer {
    
    public MiBoxRenderer() {
        setOpaque(true);
        setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD | Font.ITALIC, 16));
        setBackground(new Color(255, 153, 51));
        setForeground(Color.BLUE);
    }

    @Override
    public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list, Object value, int index, boolean isSelected,
            boolean cellHasFocus) {
        setText(value.toString());
        return this;
    }
    
}

class MiBoxEditor extends BasicComboBoxEditor {
    private JLabel label = new JLabel();
    private JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    private Object selectedItem;
     
    public MiBoxEditor() {
         
        label.setOpaque(false);
        label.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 16));
        label.setForeground(Color.RED);
         
        panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT, 5, 2));
        panel.add(label);
        panel.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
    }
     
    public Component getEditorComponent() {
        return this.panel;
    }
     
    public Object getItem() {
        return "[" + this.selectedItem.toString() + "]";
    }
     
    public void setItem(Object item) {
        this.selectedItem = item;
        label.setText(item.toString());
    }
}
```